# Selecting elements with a class starting with abc

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("[class^='stage']").addClass("hidden");
```

The above hides:

```
<div class="stage1">
<div class="stage2">
<div class="stage1 beep">
<div class="stage2 beep">
```

But it misses:

```
<div class="beep stage1">
<div class="beep stage2">
```

So I've used:

```
$("[class*='stage']").addClass("hidden");
```

The problem is that I now hide even:

```
<div class="beep vastage">
<div class="destagel beep">
```

How can I design my selector so it brings me stuff that "contains stuff that starts with stuff"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
$('*').filter(function () { 
  return $(this).attr('class') !== undefined ?
             $(this).attr('class').match(/\bstage\d*\b/g) : false;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Woah... This was cumbersome. It solves the problem, of course, but I think it'll be better to change the class name into something that differs from the other names entirely. The syntax will improve the readability. Nevertheless - good answer! +1

Comment: Surely this answer is the worst way to handle such an issue, because it will iterate through all the elements of the document, it's not fast at all, a better solution would be to change something in the HTML to make the solution much quicker, just like @KonradViltersten said.

Answer (score 0):

According to Jquery Documentation (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/), you can use the following syntax :

```
jQuery( "[attribute~='value']" )
```

to select a word (delimited by space) containing a string... but not "starting with", just containing.

I think the best way is to use javascript indexof to locate the string you want, and check if the index is 0 or the preceding character is white space. You need a loop on all the html code to check all elements...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that doesn't resolves the issue, does it?

Comment: This is functionally identical to a class selector when used with the class attribute, so will not work.